# Kendo Grid - Clicking on a column opens another table with details of the row selected

Tags: kendo-ui, frontend

I am very new to Kendo UI Grid. I need to implement a scenario as follows:

First there will be a main grid containing the basic information as follow:

```
   | Agent Name | No. Of Products Sold
-------------------------------------------
1. |  John      |         50
2. |  Dave      |         30
```

and if we click on John, a new table opens with 50 rows (each row per Product) with multiple columns containing the details of the product. and if we click back on John the Product table should collapse.

Answer (score 0):

I just modify one the kendo examples to do a [demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aHaGO) of what you want.
But I strongly recommend take a look into the details template demo maybe you could be interested.

The principal parts are:

Html: two divs for each grid, the details grid is hidden

```
<!-- main grid -->
<div id="grid"></div>

<!-- details grid hidden-->
<div id="grid2" style="display:none"></div>
```

js: 3 data sources,

```
<script>
    var selected="";
    var lastSelected="-";

    //agents          
    var agents= [{
        AgentId : 1,
        AgentName : "John",
        Products: 50
        }, {
        AgentId : 2,
        AgentName : "Dave",
        Products: 30
   }]

   //details for agent JOHN           
   var detailsJohn = [{
       colA : "colA info ",
       colB : "colB asdas",
       colC : "colC asdas"
       }, {
       colA : "colB info ",
       colB : "colB asdas",
       colC : "colC asdas"
   }]

   //details for agent DAVE   
   var detailsDave = [{
       colA : "colA info john ",
       colB : "colB asdas john",
       colC : "colC asdas"
       }, {
       colA : "colB info deve",
       colB : "colB asdas dave",
       colC : "colC asdas"
   }]

   // event handler for row selection          
   function onChange(e) {
       selected = $.map(this.select(), function(item) {
           return $(item).text();
       });

       // set the details grid datasource       
       if(selected[0] == "John50"){
          $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(detailsJohn)
       }else{
          $("#grid2").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(detailsDave)
       }

       if(lastSelected == selected[0]){
          $("#grid2").hide()
       }else{
          $("#grid2").show()
       }    
       lastSelected = selected[0]
   }

   $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#grid").kendoGrid({
             dataSource: {
                  data: products,
                  schema: {
                      model: {
                        fields: {
                             AgentId: { type: "number" },
                             AgentName: { type: "string" },
                             Products: { type: "number" }
                           }
                        }
                      },
                  pageSize: 20
               },
              height: 150,
              change: onChange,
              selectable: true,
              scrollable: true,
              sortable: true,
              filterable: true,
              pageable: {
                  input: true,
                  numeric: false
              },
              columns: [
                 "AgentName","Products"                            
                 ]
              });

                  $("#grid2").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            data: detailsJohn,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        colA: { type: "string" },
                                        colB: { type: "string" },
                                        colC: { type: "String" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20
                        },
                        height: 150,
                       // change: onChange,
                        scrollable: true,
                        sortable: true,
                        filterable: true,
                        pageable: {
                            input: true,
                            numeric: false
                        },
                        columns: [
                            "colA","colB","colC"                            
                        ]
                    });

                });
            </script>
```